# You haven't voted on questions in a while

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, voting

There does not appear to be a dupe for this.

I am not sure of the exact calculations that trigger this notification but seeing as some questions get dozens of answers my voting on questions is very skewed. I typically answer things I see on the HNQ. Those post will usually have plenty of answers and therefore I end up voting up answers more than questions.

Currently my ratio is approximately 1:4 for questions vs. answer votes.

I get the prompt

> You haven't voted on questions in a while ...

quite frequently here on PPCG. I would like to think every post I visit gets the votes it deserves so I believe I am doing right by the site and its users.

I find this reminder mildy annoying. I am not a frequent participant on the site  and more of a drive-by coder. However I don't think this site is a victim of poor voting culture. Quite the opposite actually.

Are we are to change the threshold for this notification or turn it off altogether?

Comment: What's HNQ? (....)

Comment: Hot Network Questions

Comment: I used to get annoyed at this happening here on PPCG Meta. Luckily, the quality of questions here has gone up since, so it's been less off an issue lately.

Comment: The threshold described in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113862/message-telling-me-to-vote-on-questions

Answer (score 5):

## NO

It is ***really*** hard to write a good challenge. I find it much easier to answer vs make a challenge.

All my best challenges were not written by me. I enjoy taking old challenges and posting them. But they have so much work. I put hours in a challenge and it turned out to be meh.

Please upvote challenges more. They are hard to write.

Comment: I never said I didn't vote for questions. I said there are way more answers then questions here.

Comment: I didn't say you didn't. Less challenges per answer = challenge are worth more. It is to the point that meta posts are about giving challenges a +10 rep bonus rather than +5

Comment: My response was rubbish. Sorry about that. I suppose I need to hit SEDE to see if it is not possible to upvote more questions given, what I see as, the hugely disproportionate about of answers to vote on. I only find the notification annoying. It might be useful for others. If there was more good questions there would still be more good answers. I _think_ the issue would be the same.

Comment: @Matt yes, the real problem is how much more answers are voted. Look at the top answer on a challenge. Quite often it is a simple answer in Jelly or another golf language. The challenge took more work than answers, I know this as I have answered my challenges.

Answer (score 4):

## This is good for the site

I'm going to expand a bit on what Christopher has said.

Good questions on this site are difficult to write and extremely valuable for the site.  For most sites the goal is to get answers.  Getting questions is important, without them a site will die, but, in my opinion, not as much as they are here.  Here the goal is to compete and collaborate on interesting challenges.  The answers are the result but not really the goal (the old its the journey not the destination cliché).  This makes good questions way more important than good answers.

People should be incentivized to vote on *good* questions as it helps to keep our good question writers interested in making good questions.  Since questions get half as much rep as answers you need to get more votes for it to be worth often larger time investment put into writing quality questions.

This message should encourage users that don't often vote on questions to do so.  For a drive-by-voter such as yourself, I would recommend looking elsewhere for good questions to vote on, I think the HNQ questions are generally not that good while a lot of high quality questions do not actually appear in the HNQ. And if you don't want to look past the HNQ, just remember downvotes are free ;)

---

That being said I don't think there is a real answer skew in the current voting culture.  Believe me, there are problems with the sites voting culture (my top voted answer is [this mediocre answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96642/56656), and [my top question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/110485/leak-memory-in-as-few-bytes-as-possible) is not much better), but I don't think we have a big voting skew problem.

But this warning is a good skew prevention system.  Users like yourself, no offense intended, should probably vote on more questions.  The message may be annoying but I think it does good for the site.

Comment: No offense taken. I think though I might have worded my question here poorly. I can't vote on more questions without ignoring answers is more my point. If I read the question and it has answers I will likely vote on them as well. True, there are questions without answers yet and I have voted on them. I want to vote on good posts. I just find more of them are answers. I get the jist of what both of your are saying. This is not my primary site so likely I am not familiar with the site as I thought.

Comment: Nice job, you really finished what I wrote. Good job